# canvas not drawing images in another method

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

I have extended View to use canvas. I have draw basic drawings in onDraw() method, when user touches in the canvas I have to draw an image there, for that I have used canvas inside onTouchEvent() method,it is not drawing anything there, the code is given below, what is the problem and how can i resolve this

```
public class ScreenView extends View(){

  static Canvas canvas;
    Bitmap bm;

    protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        this.canvas = canvas;
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        canvas.draw.......
        ......
        ...........


    }
    public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent event) {

        handleTouches(event.getX(), event.getY());

        return false;
    }
    public void handleTouches(float x, float y) {
        xLocTouch = (int) x;
        yLocTouched = (int) y;
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bm, xLocTouch ,yLocTouched , paint);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use a Canvas in onDraw method only, (and related: dispatchDraw(),  draw())

Answer (score 0):

You should call `invalidate()` method inside `onTouchEvent`, then your `onDraw()` method will be called, and you just should store your `x` and `y` coordinates, and then draw bitmap to this coordinates, like this:

```
public class ScreenView extends View {
    int xLocTouched;
    int yLocTouched;
    Bitmap bm;

    protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        //your basic drawings also should depends on xLocTouched and yLocTouched.

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bm, xLocTouched ,yLocTouched , paint);

    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent event) {
        xLocTouched = (int) event.getX();
        yLocTouched = (int) event.getY();

        invalidate();

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: but if I touched twice previous touch data will lose from the canvas. can I persist old data and redraw again ?